# How to implement pygment syntax highlighting in django admin change_form?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pygments

I want to pygmentize my text field python code in django admin template in a situation.

I have a python code block which is stored as a text field in django model.Here i stand with the situation of highlighting that python code with syntax in django admin change_form.html whenever you try to access that, it would be in proper syntax highlighiting style.

I have gone through some resources.

All are explained to make **django template tag or filter** with custom pygment template tag also, i got some nice article too.

1.http://od-eon.com/blogs/stefan/integrating-pygments-django/

2.http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/416/

But I am facing problem of using the template tags or filters in django admin **change_form.html** ?

Or How can we do the syntax highlighting through django model admin if this is the method should need to be passed (http://dpaste.com/hold/1280580/)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need ordering on the python code column, then you could simply render it using [pygments API](http://pygments.org/docs/quickstart/#example) in a ModelAdmin method using [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display). Then you wouldn't need to touch django admin templates at all.

Comment: list_display used in change_list.html to display fields as columns right? but I have to do in change_form.html in the text field be highlighted with detected syntax

Comment: Right, then edit your topic and talk about change_form instead of changelist_form, thanks !